# How to generate commands which are very similar?

Tags: function-construction, interpolation, map

I have several data sets that I wish to interpolate and integrate like this:

```
g1 = Interpolation[q1, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
s1 = NIntegrate[Abs[g1[t]], {t, 0, q1[[Length[q1], 1]]}, Method -> Automatic]
```

Basically, `g1` will be replaced by `g2,g3,g4...`, `q1` by `q2,q3,q4...`, `s1` by `s2,s3,s4...`.

I do not want to write duplicate commands. Is there any way for *Mathematica* to run  by itself? So can I give something like

```
{g1,g2,g3}=Interpolation[{g1,g2,g3},Interpolationorder->1];
```

Many thanks!

--------UPDATE--------

I tried

```
    r1a = {{0, 0.315`}, {0.19`, 0.508`}, {0.314`, 0.679`}, {0.587`, 
   0.959`}, {0.895`, 1.179`}, {1.204`, 1.326`}, {1.513`, 
   1.447`}, {1.822`, 1.521`}, {2.131`, 1.602`}, {2.44`, 
   1.671`}, {2.749`, 1.728`}, {3.058`, 1.783`}, {3.367`, 
   1.814`}, {3.676`, 1.851`}, {3.985`, 1.869`}, {4.294`, 
   1.902`}, {4.603`, 1.921`}, {4.912`, 1.94`}, {5.22`, 
   1.956`}, {5.529`, 1.968`}, {5.838`, 1.979`}, {6.147`, 
   1.967`}, {6.456`, 1.963`}, {6.765`, 1.979`}, {7.074`, 
   1.985`}, {7.383`, 1.975`}, {7.692`, 1.957`}, {7.964`, 1.953`}}

    r2a = {{0.007`, 0.369`}, {0.077`, 0.592`}, {0.148`, 0.742`}, {0.185`, 
   0.97`}, {0.356`, 1.262`}, {0.458`, 1.496`}, {0.565`, 
   1.727`}, {0.788`, 2.083`}, {0.715`, 1.893`}, {0.938`, 
   2.226`}, {1.074`, 2.424`}, {1.224`, 2.558`}, {1.365`, 
   2.692`}, {1.519`, 2.816`}, {1.686`, 2.896`}, {1.845`, 
   3.015`}, {2.006`, 3.075`}, {2.168`, 3.139`}, {2.327`, 
   3.212`}, {2.494`, 3.272`}, {2.645`, 3.348`}, {2.813`, 
   3.373`}, {2.97`, 3.46`}, {3.141`, 3.485`}, {3.287`, 
   3.533`}, {3.462`, 3.546`}, {3.629`, 3.577`}, {3.799`, 
   3.606`}, {3.939`, 3.641`}, {4.121`, 3.675`}, {4.277`, 
   3.719`}, {4.422`, 3.739`}, {4.591`, 3.733`}, {4.756`, 
   3.751`}, {4.931`, 3.742`}, {5.073`, 3.764`}, {5.241`, 
   3.772`}, {5.402`, 3.771`}, {5.564`, 3.778`}, {5.726`, 
   3.771`}, {5.885`, 3.772`}, {6.049`, 3.8`}, {6.211`, 3.8`}, {6.372`,
    3.802`}, {6.534`, 3.801`}, {6.696`, 3.797`}, {6.857`, 
   3.801`}, {7.019`, 3.801`}, {7.181`, 3.799`}, {7.339`, 
   3.773`}, {7.504`, 3.766`}, {7.656`, 3.753`}, {7.827`, 
   3.745`}, {7.989`, 3.745`}, {8.15`, 3.749`}, {8.315`, 
   3.732`}, {8.474`, 3.745`}, {8.635`, 3.712`}, {8.806`, 
   3.696`}, {8.958`, 3.674`}, {9.076`, 3.652`}}

    {i1, i2} = Interpolation[#, InterpolationOrder -> 1] & /@ {r1a, r2a}
```

Comment: Consider using `Map`. For instance, you could write: `{fg1, fg2, fg3} = Interpolation[#, InterpolationOrder -> 1]& /@ {g1, g2, g3}`

Comment: Hi! I tried your advice but met a little problem. Would you mind taking a look at it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Copy and paste the code and data as text in your question, rather than a screenshot, so we can reproduce what you are trying.

Comment: Marc, take a look at the sample I put in an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for this you can use `Map` (as operator `/@`) which is one of the most often used functions when doing the same job for several inputs. For instance creating 3 data sets

```
{g1, g2, g3} = Range /@ {10, 20, 30}
```

and then creating your interpolations

```
{i1, i2, i3} = Interpolation[#, InterpolationOrder -> 1] & /@ {g1, g2, g3}
```

If you don't know what the `#` symbol does, then please read about [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html).

If we apply this to your example, then we get:

```
r1a = {{0, 0.315`}, {0.19`, 0.508`}, {0.314`, 0.679`}, {0.587`, 
   0.959`}, {0.895`, 1.179`}, {1.204`, 1.326`}, {1.513`, 
   1.447`}, {1.822`, 1.521`}, {2.131`, 1.602`}, {2.44`, 
   1.671`}, {2.749`, 1.728`}, {3.058`, 1.783`}, {3.367`, 
   1.814`}, {3.676`, 1.851`}, {3.985`, 1.869`}, {4.294`, 
   1.902`}, {4.603`, 1.921`}, {4.912`, 1.94`}, {5.22`, 
   1.956`}, {5.529`, 1.968`}, {5.838`, 1.979`}, {6.147`, 
   1.967`}, {6.456`, 1.963`}, {6.765`, 1.979`}, {7.074`, 
   1.985`}, {7.383`, 1.975`}, {7.692`, 1.957`}, {7.964`, 1.953`}}

r2a = {{0.007`, 0.369`}, {0.077`, 0.592`}, {0.148`, 0.742`}, {0.185`, 
    0.97`}, {0.356`, 1.262`}, {0.458`, 1.496`}, {0.565`, 
    1.727`}, {0.788`, 2.083`}, {0.715`, 1.893`}, {0.938`, 
    2.226`}, {1.074`, 2.424`}, {1.224`, 2.558`}, {1.365`, 
    2.692`}, {1.519`, 2.816`}, {1.686`, 2.896`}, {1.845`, 
    3.015`}, {2.006`, 3.075`}, {2.168`, 3.139`}, {2.327`, 
    3.212`}, {2.494`, 3.272`}, {2.645`, 3.348`}, {2.813`, 
    3.373`}, {2.97`, 3.46`}, {3.141`, 3.485`}, {3.287`, 
    3.533`}, {3.462`, 3.546`}, {3.629`, 3.577`}, {3.799`, 
    3.606`}, {3.939`, 3.641`}, {4.121`, 3.675`}, {4.277`, 
    3.719`}, {4.422`, 3.739`}, {4.591`, 3.733`}, {4.756`, 
    3.751`}, {4.931`, 3.742`}, {5.073`, 3.764`}, {5.241`, 
    3.772`}, {5.402`, 3.771`}, {5.564`, 3.778`}, {5.726`, 
    3.771`}, {5.885`, 3.772`}, {6.049`, 3.8`}, {6.211`, 
    3.8`}, {6.372`, 3.802`}, {6.534`, 3.801`}, {6.696`, 
    3.797`}, {6.857`, 3.801`}, {7.019`, 3.801`}, {7.181`, 
    3.799`}, {7.339`, 3.773`}, {7.504`, 3.766`}, {7.656`, 
    3.753`}, {7.827`, 3.745`}, {7.989`, 3.745`}, {8.15`, 
    3.749`}, {8.315`, 3.732`}, {8.474`, 3.745`}, {8.635`, 
    3.712`}, {8.806`, 3.696`}, {8.958`, 3.674`}, {9.076`, 3.652`}};

{i1, i2} = Interpolation[#, InterpolationOrder -> 1] & /@ {r1a, r2a};
```

Now, `i1` and `i2` contain the two interpolation functions. We could plot for instance the points of `r1a` and the interpolation together in one graphic to see that it worked:

```
Show[
 ListPlot[r1a, PlotStyle -> Red],
 Plot[i1[x], {x, 0, 7.96}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Hi! I tried your advice but met a little problem. Would you mind taking a look at it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Would you close as trivial? Your answer is immediately helpful, but the issue is quite basic.

Comment: @YvesKlett Sorry I am a novice...I feel sorry

Comment: @Marc Dear Marc, no reason the feel sorry! And welcome! I was just asking for @halirutan´s take on the question. It is great that you got quick help, sometimes questions on basic issues may be closed anyway...

Comment: Would've used `Scan[]` myself… :)

Comment: @Marc I have used your example code and showed you, that the approach indeed works. Please have a look.

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked out!

Comment: what if I want to calculate the area under the curve, say                                               {s1, s2} = 
 NIntegrate[#[sb], {sb, 0, #[[Length[#], 1]]}, 
    Method -> Automatic] & /@ {i1, r1a, r1a, i2, r2a, r2a}

Comment: @Marc, no need to use `NIntegrate[]` for `InterpolatingFunction[]` objects, `Integrate[]` can deal with the underlying polynomials. You might also be interested to know that if, say, `ip` is an `InterpolatingFunction[]`, `ip["Domain"]` will yield the domain you want to integrate on.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible implementation of what I was proposing, to get you started:

```
Plot[
 Interpolation[#, InterpolationOrder -> 1][x] & /@ {r1a, r2a},
 {x, 0, 9.1}, Evaluated -> True,
 Epilog -> {{Red, Point[r1a]}, {Blue, Point[r2a]}}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I've been told `Table[]` works here as well: `Table[Interpolation[r, InterpolationOrder -> 1][x], {r, {r1a, r2a}}]`.

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked out!

Comment: @Marc I'm glad to hear it! I'd appreciate your up vote if you think that my answer was useful to you!

Comment: Sorry MarcoB, I'd love to vote your answer but my rank is too low to be eligible to vote.  :(

Comment: @Marc No worries! I voted up your question, that should help you along, and you can always come back at a later time after you unlock the voting privilege.